# How to prevent moment js to covert the timestamp based on the server timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have timestamp in milliseconds which I want to convert to human readable format as it is.But `moment js` convert the timestamp as per the server's timezone. In fact, the timestamp is already in UTC timezone only. `moment js` converts it again to `UTC`. How to inform `moment js` that the given timestamp is already in `UTC` and not convert it again based on server's timezone.

Please consider the given code: 
`moment(parseInt('1561407163043')).format("LLLL")`

Answer (score 1):

Use `moment.utc`

```
moment.utc(parseInt('1561407163043')).format("LLLL")
```

See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/ for more details

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to lock the offset to insure its the timezone you parse is on a GMT offset of your choice. If I understand correctly, I had a similar case where my resource had data on its server's time, but my client server had its own time and when I ran reports, I had to decide what time to use based on the logged time and my decided offset.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/